# New terminal tabs have root privileges, how to stop it

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, gnome-terminal

I have a simple bash script which opens several terminals

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e "tail -5f /home/myuser/projects/logs/db.log"  --window-with-profile=MyProfile --geometry=228x24+1920+0
gnome-terminal -e "mysql -uroot dbname"  --window-with-profile=MyProfile --geometry=228x24+1920+415
gnome-terminal -e "sudo tail -5f /tmp/uwsgi.log"  --window-with-profile=MyProfile --geometry=228x24+1920+835
```

and then I have an alias which runs the script as root:

```
alias openterminals='sudo /usr/local/bin/openterminals'
```

I do this because I want to be asked for my password only once at the beginning of the script, instead of inside every tabs, where it's required.

However, there is one problem with this approach -> if I open a new tab inside one of these terminals, it got opened as root. Is there any chance to prevent this?

PS. I know I can achieve this by removing `sudo` from the alias, but I'm looking for a solution which will preserve it.

Comment: I currently don't have an idea yet how to do this properly, but you definitely should not launch `gnome-terminal` or any other GUI application with `sudo` at all.

Comment: @ByteCommander, maybe I could keep running the script with sudo, but inside of it I could start the gnome-terminal w/o root privileges. I tried to do it with several ways with `sudo -u user command` and `su <user> -c <command>` but cant make it work (got different kind of errors which I'm still debugging).